# JQuery UI Draggable custom helper doesn't work correctly in IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7

I want to use a custom helper in a web application I'm working on for displaying some text about the highlighted item, in this case a 'friendly' name.  I've chosen JQuery UI as my plugin.  Unfortunately, I need to support users on IE7 and that's not negotiable.  The demo on Jquery's web-site works as expected in IE7:

```
$( "#draggable3" ).draggable({
cursor: "move",
cursorAt: { top: -12, left: -20 },
helper: function( event ) {
return $( "<div class='ui-widget-header'>I'm a custom helper</div>" );
}
});
```

However, when I copy this and place it in my own web-site it doesn't work in IE7 but works in FireFox, Chrome, and Opera.  By not work I mean that the cursor changes correctly and the 'draggable' state is active but the helper text isn't displayed.

To fix it I've tried using 'zoom:1;', 'z-index:9999;' but also 'position:relative;' and 'position:absolute;', which leaves me wondering 'Have I missed something?' Hopefully someone else has encountered this problem and can shed some light on it for us all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you're still having this problem, but add this one line.

```
$( "#draggable3" ).draggable({
    appendTo: 'body',
    cursor: "move",
    cursorAt: { top: -12, left: -20 },
    helper: function( event ) {
        return $( "<div class='ui-widget-header'>I'm a custom helper</div>" );
    }
});
```

Your helper div is getting appended somewhere weird; mine was at the bottom of a table where it could only be seen because it was jacking up my table borders.